# Where to view favorite questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I have marked few questions as favorite by highlighting star mark. But I do not see any link to see favorite questions. Is there any way to see it ?

Answer (score 1):

your favourites will be in a location similar to

*https://stackoverflow.com/users/idnumberhere/usernamehere?tab=favorites*

So in your case they would be at

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2611521/rakesh-babu?tab=favorites

They are accessible via your user page as a tab about halfway down on the right of the page
[image: Favourites location]

I suspect this question may have been better suited to the meta version of this site  [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: erm yep, all sorted, will delete the comments:)

Answer (score 1):

It's on the favorites tab of your user profile, which can be accessed via the link to your profile on every page, or directly by URL in the form of:

http:// (stack-exchange-site).com/users/current?tab=favorites

Comment: Oooh. I didn't know about `/users/current`. That's helpful.